# INDEX MATCH with multiple matches. Find the MAX match

Tags: worksheet-function, array, microsoft-excel-365

I ran a GIS operation that provided me with a table to show the 3 closest lengths of pipe to a valve. Main line pipe comes in 12,8,6 & 4 inch sizes and outputs to 4,3 & inch lateral lines.

I had the table output 3 values for each valve as they can often be placed in a tee shape with an 8" mainline a valve leading to 4" lateral. In cases like this, I want to put the valve on the 8" line, then produce a 8x6 reducer. Running a single result NEAR at this location may output 6" due to the CAD architect's placement.

My question to you is how do I get a MAX() for the pipe size for each valve? I have 221 valves for 663 lines and cannot do this manually.

Things I have tried:

- `INDEX(MATCH())` gets the first result from the top down and moves on. I need it to output an array so I can nest that output in a `MAX()` or find the place to nest the MAX()
- Sort by distance to valve and remove all values above 10 feet. This works for some but certainly not all. goes from a 663line operation to a ~325 line operation. if it were a 221 line operation I wouldn't need help but it looks like there's a lot of `pipe^valve>reducer>pipe` locations opposed to `pipe^valve>pipe` locations

| Valve | Near Rank | Near pipe size | blank | Unique Valve | Highest | INDEX(MATCH()) Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 8 |  | 1 | 8 | 8 |
| 1 | 2 | 8 |  | 2 | 6 | 4 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 |  | 3 | 8 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 6 |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2 | 4 |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 1 | 4 |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 2 | 8 |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 3 | 6 |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In office 365 as you have tagged, you can use FILTER and MAX.

If I correctly understand your requirement, see below screenshot. I assume Near Rank is not used, if so formula will change.

[image]

Cell I4 in above example.

```
=UNIQUE(D4:D12)
```

Cell J4 in above example.

```
=MAX(FILTER($F$4:$F$12,$D$4:$D$12=I4))
```

Drag down the formula from J4 below up to intended rows.

Comment: Perfect! Your assumption was correct, the rank column was only included to help conceptualize that valve 1 has 3 values. I'd used filter before but mostly to remove zeros from arrays to turn them into blanks